# What is the approach for solving these kinds of modular arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic

I am new to modular arithmetic. I have gone through a few formulae related to this but I am unable to solve problems like (5^12) mod 23. I am not really bothered about the final answer, but mainly on the approach on these kinds of problems (or maybe more involving complex powers). Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please read the following: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation

Comment: Fermat's little theorem and Euler's totient function come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

- Rewriting "big" numbers like $920 \,\rm{mod}\, 1000$ as "smaller" numbers: $920 \equiv -80$.
- Finding patterns in exponents (for example, $2^n \,\rm{mod}\, 10$ has a cycle $2,\, 4,\, 8,\, 6$ with $4$ steps).
- Reducing big exponents using Euler's $\phi$.
- Squaring **(!)**. For example, in $231^{19} \,\rm{mod}\,517$, you might find, first, $231^2$ and then use that $231^{19} = {(231^2)}^9\times 231$. Iterating this makes every congruence so, *oh so* much easier..

Those are the main techniques I'm aware of.